# Combine Sphinx documentation from several Projects

Tags: python-sphinx

In our team we have several Projects, each separately documented with Sphinx.
We want to have a central documentation page, which includes all of our projects.

Of course we could build a HTML page with links to the different documentations.

Is there a way to combine the documentations with Sphinx itself?
Maybe with a separate Documentation project, which somehow includes the documentation from the other projects?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [intersphinx](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/intersphinx.html) to create links between existing documentations. This works like Wikipedia links to other Wikis in the Wikimedia universe.

An alternative is to checkout all documentation directories into a new repository. You might need to create new `toctree`s because it either doesn't fit into the overall structure or the nesting gets to deep. Therefore you could provide alternative index files by changing the index file name to e.g. `master.rst`.

An individual documentation is build by using the original `index.rst` but if it's used in the master documentation, only `master.rst` files will be considered as `toctree`s.